# Should we assign a subjective importance, priority, problem degree or problem size for an OP's question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

A programmer asked What are the priorities? I put it like

What is the difference between our worst problem and the least problem?

referring to that sometimes a technician spends time working on low-priority problem when we should make the common case.

Could it be an idea to use some measure how "severe" the problem being solved by the question is? For instance if I ask about some graphics detail that is not crucial but "eye candy" then I could flag the question low priority for me. And if I must solve a blocking bug that blocks an entire project with a short deadline then I could mark the question high priority.

Is it a good new idea or was it already considered?

Comment: SO's not a support platforms with SLAs & people paid to uphold them. Your priorities are your own. People answer based on what they feel like answering.

Comment: I prioritize my emails by the inverse of the self assigned priority field. It's amazingly effective.

Comment: Ok. I notice that nowadays email priority is almost never used. It was conveneitn to see that the sender at some time didn't think himself that he was asking something important. While it's very clear if somebody sends you a message saying "This is very important" first.

Answer (score 15):

There are bounties which can be used to attract more attention to a question by offering extra rep and displaying them on the featured tab.

As for priority, I don't think it's a good idea because :

- your question may be extremely important to you, but in the end you're only one of several hundred thousand users, so why would your "top priority" question be more important than someone else's "top priority" question ?
- the feature will always be abused by help vampires and other users who post crap questions... in the end it will be a "help vampire level" indicator rather than a priority indicator, which actually wouldn't be that bad if you want to go on a downvote/closevote/flag spree.
- upvotes do that already, if the question is relevant to a large audience (for example, asking for a workaround to a bug in a new language) it is likely to be upvoted many times and thus *appear to be* more important than other low-score questions.
- in the end, if that feature would end up being implemented the only way to get your question answered is to post it as top priority, which means everyone would do that and the indicator would be useless.

Comment: "in the end it will be a 'help vampire level' indicator rather than a priority indicator" Hmmm... maybe that's an argument *for* such a feature! ;)

Comment: I meant as easy as high/medium/low priority like we had for emails. You can assign a low priority to an email message without having to compare it to someone else's. If your questions are always asked for someone else then you might not be as happy compared to asking and prioritzing your questions for your own sake. Like subjective importance for for the OP. Somebody might think it's important to fix program for something that is worthless for us e.g. old 8-bit equipment with no market value that is no use for us than can be important for the OP while not interesting for the others.

Comment: @NiklasRtz as said many times already, who cares how the question is important to the asker. Plus, the feature would be abused and the only way to have a question answered is to mark it as high priority.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Who cares? Answer: He who actually is looking for the "worst game ever"

Answer (score 12):

To be blunt, nobody cares how important the question is to the asker.

If a problem is important to you, then the best way to get attention is to make an interesting and well-written question about it. Answerers are attracted to intriguing problems. They're going to try to solve those problems that they have time for and either knowledge or curiosity about.

Answer (score 5):

On top of the other good answers, a question that is perceived as low priority by the asker may be of high priority for some lucky contributor who just happens to have seen exactly that problem before, spent a day debugging it, knows the exact fix and needs the rep.

Works both ways:)