# Suggestion: Challenge ratings for questions

Tags: feature-request

Recently, the question [Is it ever okay to ask obvious question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283422/is-it-ever-okay-to-ask-obvious-questions/283434) raised a bit of a discussion.

As a matter of fact, this type of questions has saved me a lot of time over the years.

On the downside, the easy questions drown out the really tough ones. About 20% of the questions go unanswered. 2,225,102 at this time.

Tough questions require more knowledge, take more time to answer and are quickly drowned by the flow of new questions.

Meanwhile, tough questions offer little reputation compared to simple but popular questions. A simple, obvious question means many answers and many upvotes (people search for common problems, and they are more able to understand and validate answers to these questions).

A tough question, on the other end, is a question where only a few people know the answer and often targets an obscure area of programming. Most people can't upvote because they might not even understand the question nor the answer, and few people will look for the question either.

Answering tough questions paradoxically gives much less reputation than answering simple already-in-the-manual type of questions.

One way to alleviate the problem could be to implement a challenge rating for questions. It could work this way:

easy, regular, tough, pro, elite

1. Users <2k rep can mark their questions as "easy" or "regular".
2. users >2k rep & <5k rep can mark questions as "easy", "regular" & "tough"
3. users > 5k rep & < 10k rep can mark questions as "easy", "regular",
   "tough" & "pro"
4. users > 10k rep can mark questions as they please.

The person rating a question as "tough" or above can not answer the question for a week (meaning you would rate a question as tough only if you don't know the answer).

Questions would produce rep based on their challenge ratings, giving extra incentive to answer tough questions.

Additionally, a question challenge rating would automatically increase over time if unanswered. If something ranked easy isn't answered within a day, obviously it wasn't that easy and so it becomes "regular". If there is still no answer within a week, the question was probably tough, and so on.

Questions with high challenge ratings would be easy to find and act as puzzles for the top guys who can't be bothered with the pedestrian questions.

On the other end of the spectrum, "Easy" questions could/should be capped in terms of reputation. As useful as obvious questions are, you really shouldn't be able to earn 4,910 points for quoting 2 lines from Python's manual, let alone earning 1,885 points for asking how to do basic IO in Python.

Comment: There's upvotes and bounties already. Don't see a need for such.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this have been requested (and rejected) before but I cannot find the dupe link(s).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Upvotes and bounties are completely orthogonal to difficulty level. I don't see how they address this. Remember, simple questions aren't necessarily "bad" questions.

Comment: MSE duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3811/how-about-a-difficulty-rating-for-questions

Comment: @rene: Nearly, but this time we have the factor that new users wouldn't be able to hit 'Expert'. The so-called "duplicate" never had that and, as such, much of the conversation revolved around new users choosing to think their question is 'expert'. Anyway, given how everyone always says "I have a simple doubt Can u help me" I dispute that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah, maybe I should have said related but I agree with you that it is hard if not impossible to make this fly...

Comment: Related question : http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281547/2629998

Answer (score 11):

That won't work.

People with less than 2k rep fall into two categories:

- Clueless people who won't know how to categorise their question (your idea broken there)
- Knowledgeable people who simply haven't been on SO much before, but may post a complex question (your idea broken there)

Even if it did work, you'd be splintering the community into help vampires and their enablers answering stupid typo questions, and the "elite" who prefer esoteric, academic pursuits. I can't imagine that to be a good thing.

Comment: I don't see how these 2 categories break the system. Clueless people are restricted to "regular" (default) or "easy". No damage there. Knowledgeable people who haven't been long on SO CAN post complex questions, but they can't rate them as such until their rep is high enough, the same way they can't edit answers or vote to close questions or have any of the other privileges. Other users can, however change the rating of the question. Failing that, time will do the work.
Re: segregation, it exists de facto, except that simple questions have a dozen answers and hard questions don't.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Right, so you're suggesting we introduce a system of categorising questions by difficulty in which, by design, the bulk of question-askers cannot actually accurately categorise their questions by difficulty? Sounds great. Re: segregation, no you're wrong.

Comment: The real deal is not having askers categorize questions. It's having potential answerers do the job. You are good at C++ and a question stumps you. You can't answer. The asker is in deep trouble, it's a really tough question. His odds of getting an answer are very low. His question will soon dive in the depths of the unanswered section. But if YOU mark it as "elite", you call the attention of people who might be able to help the asker. And they know the question is worth their time because someone like you couldn't answer.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Meh. Well if you want to attract certain people, then that opens up another can of words, which is that a question that is very difficult for one person may be easy for another. You're over-simplifying the notion of "difficulty". Really, tags are the best way to attract sub-audiences.

Comment: We have 2+M unanswered questions and we have had tags since day one, so one can safely assume that tags will not resolve the problem. IMHO, solving the problem of unanswered questions requires a mechanism for bringing these questions to the attention of people who can answer them and encourage them to do so. I am not saying the first draft of my proposal is perfect or can't be improved, but I think the idea of a challenge rating is worth exploring.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: We do not need to find people to answer the 2+M unanswered questions. We need to nuke them. They are rubbish. Anyway I have already explained why the rating system won't work, as have the gentlemen and ladies in the near-duplicate post.

Comment: The role of a QA site is to provide answers to people's questions. When people ask valid questions (can't be closed) and don't get an answer, it's not "rubbish", it's failure. Some of these rubbish questions have 1000's of views. With all due respect, no you have yet to give a valid argument as to why a challenge rating wouldn't work. Neither of the categories mentioned in your answer affect the challenge rating mechanism as described. re: segregation, people answer the questions they want to answer. Making it easier for them to find these is a good thing, IMHO.

Comment: @Sylverdrag: Yes it would be but your proposal does not do that

Answer (score 9):

> this type of questions has saved me a lot of time over the years.

No. Google saved you a lot of time.  And used to always rank the SO posts first.  So it just *looked* like those questions where useful to you.

That's over, Google now favors sites that have original content instead.  The way it should be, maintained by whatever organization is behind that content and cares about it staying current and accurate.  SO has turned into a link-trap, ever more questions getting added from users that don't do any research, questions that are just closed as duplicate, linking to the stale old answer.  Google doesn't like link-traps.  Nobody does.

These kind of questions should be *deleted*.  That's awfully hard to do.  We can't get 10K questions closed, deleting a million is a staggering task.  Only way forward is to prevent them from getting added.

Comment: This type of questions saves time. Nobody writes "original content" in the form of a 3 line answer to a simple common question. That "doesn't warrant an article or a web page". If you remove SO questions, the remaining SERP to this type of questions are in the form of a wall of text that needs to be read through and that might not even contain the answer because it's "too obvious". These tend to be evergreen too: the basics of file I/O and such don't change anywhere near as much as the rest.

Comment: A link to an outdated 3-liner answer does *not* save time.  Far from it.

Comment: Compared to a link to an outdated 3000 word tutorial... Simple questions are often made of evergreen. Could be outdated, of course, but the same is true for every other resource online.

Answer (score 4):

The author is least likely to be the right person to assess the difficulty of the question. Leaving it to some kind of voting by tag experts might work, but would it be worth the complexity? Doubtful. A well-written question about a "pro" subject is usually pretty clear as to its interest factor. A poorly-written question isn't likely to get categorized correctly anyways, until it gets edited, at which point it becomes a well-written question. There are also a fair few questions where the high-rep author thinks the problem is deep and intricate, but it's actually some kind of oversight.

As a user who has a bit of expertise in a topic or two, I would welcome anything that I thought would help me find more interesting questions and ignore the boring ones, but this functionality isn't it.

Comment: 97% of users have less than 2000 rep and would only have the right to mark their question as easy or regular. No biggie. Above 2000 in rep, you have people very familiar with the type of questions posted and they have some idea if a question is actually difficult. Someone above 10K rep (top 0.25%) can say "my, this is tricky". Implementation-wise, "tough question", "pro question", etc. could simply be special tags restricted to users with the required rep. In every other respect it would behave like a normal tag. I am not privy to SO source code, but I doubt the complexity is an issue.

Comment: I was thinking mostly of the complexity on the user end.

Answer (score 4):

> Additionally, a question challenge rating would automatically increase over time if unanswered. If something ranked easy isn't answered within a day, obviously it wasn't that easy and so it becomes "regular". If there is still no answer within a week, the question was probably tough, and so on.

The correlation between how long a question remains unanswered and how much it challenges answerers is a weak one. Some questions just fall between the cracks. Some questions are tagged and have a title that make people think the issue is with a technology that few people are familiar with when in fact the issue is with something most people could answer quickly *if they just read the question*. Etc. These questions do not remain unanswered because they are challenging.

In the less popular tags, increasing the "challenge rating" of a question that remains unanswered for a while would just encourage people who could answer to wait. Yes, it *is* a gamble because someone else could answer first, but not a very risky gamble because the tag is not popular.

> The person rating a question as "tough" or above can not answer the question for a week (meaning you would rate a question as tough only if you don't know the answer).

This could have a perverse effect in the less popular tags because it may very well be that the only person who *can* rate your question as "tough" is the *only* person who has an answer.

But maybe I'm jumping the gun here, because the feature request here does not detail of how the "challenge rating" would be managed in the case the community is not in agreement about how challenging a question is or how the rating may change over time. For instance, one way around the "rate as tough, be blocked from answering for a week" rule would be to answer first and *then* rate the question as tough. Or maybe the idea is that the rating becomes locked in at some point. But what event would cause a rating to be locked in, and why should challenge ratings somehow be exempt from the input of later users? After all, questions and answers that are not deleted or locked in some fashion (and locking is the *exception*, not the rule) are open to voting forever.

Comment: People chasing after points won't wait for a question challenge rating to increase. The easiest way to high rep is answering lots of simple common questions. 5000 points for python file open snippet. Can't beat that! Waiting for an obscure question to become tough? You have to track the question, wait until it becomes good and juicy, then rush and compete with other users doing the same. If only one person on SO can answer it, it's one hell of a tough question and the one guy who can answer it deserves the boost.

Comment: Python is not a less popular tag, so your example is irrelevant. Waiting for an "obscure" (your word) question to become "tough" would not be as hard as you imagine. I'm active in less popular tags. I've not rarely seen a question that was "meh" and I could not be bothered to answer right away even if I could. There were more interesting question to answer elsewhere. A few days later I saw it acquired a bounty! I did not have to track anything. In the less popular tags the low volume makes it really easy to know what is going on.

Comment: And, if only one person has the knowledge to answer it does not mean the question is *difficult*. It just means it is more "obscure" (as you put it). If someone asks "how to frobble with library foo" and the answer is right there spelled out in the documentation of foo but there's only one person on SO who has used foo before, it does not make the question *difficult*.